# Vue/React: Proper way to call functions to pass down data?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

So I'm confused to the best way to pass down data when building React or Vue apps.

Method 1) I had my child components calling functions that made API calls to get/refresh data on the component.

Method 2) I just recently made the switch, wherever possible, in these child components to put these API calls in the parent and the child component calls functions that call that one in the parent, and passes the new data in as props.
Are any of these the preferred way of handling data?  Method 2 felt a little cleaner to me and it's not possible in all places but it felt like the parent should be responsible, when possible, to refresh the data, but that also makes the child dependent on the parent so I'm not sure anymore.

**METHOD 1**

```
<template>

      <div>
          <div v-for="(prod,index) in this.products" :key=index><
              {{ prod.name }}
          </div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
        data() {
            return {
                products: []    
            }
        },
        mounted() {
             this.getProducts();
        },  
        methods: {
            getProducts: function() {
                axios.post('api/########', { 
                        this.products: response.data, 
                })

        }
</script>
```

**METHOD 2**

```
<template>
      <div>
          <div v-for="(prod,index) in products" :key=index><
              {{ prod.name }}
          </div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
        props: {
            products: {type: Array}
        }  
        methods: {
            getProducts: function() {
                this.$parent.handleGetProducts()
               *** PARENT WOULD HAVE FUNCTION HANDLEGETPRODUCTS TO MAKE THE API CALL AND PASS DOWN AND REFRESH THE PROPS GOING INTO THIS COMPONENTU**
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show some example code please?
This will help us answer your query better.

Comment: yep, just did ..sorry about that

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to unidirectional data architecture on which both Vue.js and React are based, the following guidelines should be considered:

- A child should never directly access parent component data or functions.
- It is the responsibility of parent component to pass data as **props** to its children
- Generally, things like API call (or side effects) should be put into higher-order components i.e. parents.
- In some cases, if a child component needs to tell a parent to refresh the data, then it should be done via events in Vue.js and callbacks in React. Do not really access the parent component method unless the parent has passed it as a callback prop.
- When a data needs to be shared by multiple components across different views, then consider using State containers like Vuex, Redux or MobX. Again keep in mind that state containers should be accessed by higher-order components and keep state access to minimal in case of leaf or lower-order child components.
- Alternately, Vue.js provides plugins and provide-inject mechanism for sharing data across component tree starting from designated children. In React world, Context API is the equivalent. Again, this sort of creates a strong coupling and should be used less frequently.

So what you are doing with method 2 is the long term solution keeping above guidelines in mind.

Comment: thanks!  Can you explain this: "A child should never directly access parent component data or functions" ?  Isn't my Method 2 violating this by having the child component emit an event to trigger the API call in the parent to refresh the props passed down?

Comment: Your example in Method 2 is not emitting an event, it is directly firing an event on the parent. To emit an event from the child you would do `this.$emit('event-name', data)` on the child, and receive the event on the parent like: `<child-component @event-name="handleGetProducts()"></child-component>` -- [You can read more on emitting events in Vue here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: Matt so is directly firing an event on the parent not the correct way of handling this?

Comment: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1e5t8nLw/8/). Correct. It's considered direct manipulation.  This is an anti-pattern because you are now "coupling" that child component to that specific parent. If you move that child component elsewhere to try and use it, you also have to move the parent (or else there is no method for the child to directly manipulate)... Hope that makes sense..If you emit an event to the parent, and let the parent call the method (instead of directly calling from child), this way you can now move that child wherever you want, and handle the emitted event however you want.

Comment: No problem.  Here is another example to try and help make this a little more clear: https://codesandbox.io/s/y0loz41prj

Comment: @MattOestreich sorry to bother again but in that recent example, doesnt the manual trigger that calls the parent function, `this.$parent.handleCountReached`, violate what you mentioned about coupling the parent and child?

Comment: Yes, it does - I used it as an example to show you the difference.  It is most def an anti-pattern. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: @jjoan, as Matt mentioned, Method two is correct but do not emit an event on parent using `$parent`. I hope Matt's explanation clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in two ways in React.

1. Using props - When you pass data parent to child
2. Using callback and states - When you pass data child to parent

For details you can check this article in medium [Passing Data Between React Components](https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17)